# Redux-Saga Socket Send Message

Tags: sockets, websocket, redux-saga

I am trying to send a message to a socket function "pong", but I have an arror. 
I copied code from official documentation.

> index.js:1 Error: apply: argument of type [context, fn] has undefined or null `fn` 
>       at check (io-6de156f3.js:33) 
>       at validateFnDescriptor (io-6de156f3.js:467) 
>       at apply (io-6de156f3.js:537) 
>       at pong (soket.action.js:29) 
>       at pong.next () 
>       at next (redux-saga-core.esm.js:1157) 
>       at currCb (redux-saga-core.esm.js:1251)

```
import { eventChannel, END } from 'redux-saga';
import { take, put, call, fork, apply, delay } from 'redux-saga/effects';

function createWebSocketConnection() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
        socket.onopen = function() {
            resolve(socket);
        };
        socket.onerror = function(evt) {
            reject(evt);
        };
    });
}

function createSocketChannel(socket) {
    return eventChannel(emit => {
        socket.onmessage = event => {
            emit(event.data);
        };
        return () => {
            socket.close();
        };
    });
}

function* pong(socket) {
    yield delay(5000);
    yield apply(socket, socket.emit, ['pong']); // call `emit` as a method with `socket` as context
}

export function* saga() {
    const socket = yield call(createWebSocketConnection);
    const socketChannel = yield call(createSocketChannel, socket);
    try {
        while (true) {
            console.log('work')
            const message = yield take(socketChannel);

            console.log(message);
            yield fork(pong, socket);
        }
    } catch (e) {}
}
```